# Shorter way of resolving type to the class::typedef

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, sfinae, compilation-time

I have several classes. For now they are separated by one symbol. Few of them contains `type` (a `typedef`) and few of them doesn't have it.

```
struct A { ... public: typedef someclass type; }
struct B { ... };
```

I want to implement a [SFINAE](http://en.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) class in such a way that,

```
Resolve<A>::type o1;  // should resolve to 'A::type'
Resolve<B>::type o2;  // should resolve to 'B'
```

One way is to use basic SFINAE as shown in previous link which checks if the `T` contains a `type` and then use a `bool` checker. For example,

```
template <typename T>
struct has_type {
  typedef char yes[3];
  template <typename C> static yes& test(typename C::type*);
  template <typename> static char& test(...);
  static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template<typename TYPE, bool = has_type<TYPE>::value>
struct Contains { typedef typename TYPE::type type; };
template<typename TYPE>
struct Contains<TYPE, false> { typedef TYPE type; };

template<class TYPE>
struct Resolve {
  typedef typename Contains<TYPE>::type type;
};
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/9d1sp).

**Question**: I have many such instances through out the code and I feel that this method may increase compile-time considerably. Because one has to go through two iterations: 1st for finding `type` and 2nd through resolving `bool` flag.

Is there a **faster way** to achieve to reduce the compile time ?

[Side Note: In this case, I have put `type` as separator between `A` and `B`. However, I am free to put anything inside `A` which will separate it from `B`. Ideas related to that are also welcome.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typename>
struct void_ {
    typedef void type;
};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct Resolve {
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Resolve <T, typename void_<typename T::type>::type> {
    typedef typename T::type type;
};
```

Comment: Good one. You are very fast. I feel this code is **at least** better than what I wrote. Let see if someone else offer better.

Comment: @iammilind As a warning you should make sure the code works on your end, this needs good SFINAE support.

Comment: I din't get you. Is your kind of SFINAE not supported by all compilers ? In that case should I put `#ifdef <your code> #else <my code> #endif` ?

Comment: @iammilind I actually don't know if it's allowed in C++03 or not. I know it's allowed in C++11 but keep in mind that standard has clarified some points on SFINAE (a.k.a 'extended SFINAE'). While I'm an avid user of SFINAE I really have no idea what the exact rules for C++03 are and I don't recommend you try learning them :)